# Move files from FTP to S3

Tags: ftp, amazon-s3, dreamhost, ftp-client

I have some **200-300GB** of data on my FTP which I would like to move to S3.

I don't want to download 300GB and then upload it again to S3.
Is there an easy way to simply move to S3 by using server to server transfer?

I tried using Transmit for mac and other apps, most of them download and upload.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try [ftp2cloud](http://www.ftp2cloud.com/ftp-amazon-s3/)

This might help you

Comment: that service is still in beta and not live yet.